# Is there a more concise / readable way of filtering then "double flatmapping" in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, arraylist, flatmap

I have a list of objects I want to filter, and then retrieve a list of all the distinct strings 2 layers of nested lists down. For example, to fetch the very first unfiltered result I could do:

```
mainList[0].appliedTo!![0][0]
```

However, I want all these strings from the very bottom level across all objects, in a flat list.

I have a solution, but it definitely feels suboptimal:

```
val myListOfStrings = mainList          // Start with an arraylist
    .filter { it.insertAfter == true }  // Filter the arraylist
    .flatMap { it.appliedTo.orEmpty() } // Flatmap down to a List<List<String>>
    .flatMap { it.orEmpty() }           // Flatmap down to a List<String>
    .distinct()                         // Unique values only
```

Here's how the data structure looks in the Android Studio evaluator:

[image: preview of data structure in evaluator]

Having these 4 operators seems excessive, and I'm really interested to see if the two `flatMap`s can be combined somehow. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think this is just the right way to do this. `flatMap()` is for flattening a single level, therefore to flat two levels you need two flatMaps. If you are concerned about the performance then you can use sequences - just add `.asSequence()` before `.filter()`. This way I believe it will work similarly as you would iterate items deeply, adding them to a set to get distinct items.

Comment: Good point, Android Studio suggested `asSequence` before, but I removed it whilst figuring out a solution. None of the arrays will be > 3 items, so performance isn't an issue, might add it back in regardless. I was hoping there was something niche like `flatMapBy` or `flattenAndFilter`, thanks anyway!